# How to 'factory reset'/reinstall OS on the Intel Edison

Tags: intel-edison

I've filled up my Intel Edison 100% and have no room for anything more. I've emptied all logs and am still at 100%. I decided I want to factory reset and reorganize next time with the SD card better. Unfortunately I cannot find out how to reinstall completely the OS.

I've tried downloding the Yocto linux image off the intel downloads page, and uploading that to the Edison. However, it still is running the same as before...

For some reason I distinctly remember (pretty sure anyway...) reading a command to 'reset' everything. I just can't find any documentation now that I need it. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Try this: [Flashing Edison](https://communities.intel.com/docs/DOC-23192?_ga=1.66625510.93120836.1394806742)

Comment: Thanks, found the command `reboot ota` on that page. Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the command, it's `reboot ota`

Answer (score 1):

This is my checklist

1. [Install dfu-util](https://communities.intel.com/docs/DOC-25154) (on Linux: `sudo apt-get install dfu-util`)
2. [Download Release 3.0 Yocto* complete image](https://software.intel.com/iot/hardware/edison/downloads) and unzip it
3. Connect the module using both USB connectors.
4. Run `sudo ./flashall.sh --recovery`
5. Wait for the script to finish and then a few extra minutes for the module to boot.

I've found one USB hub that didn't work, I had to connect directly to the USB port on the computer.

I'm not sure if you need both usb connectors but at least the one for main power is needed.

`flashall.sh` is found in the unzipped directory.